# Testing sound with different results

Tags: sound

I have mount surround sound in Ubuntu 14.04. When I am testing it with command:

```
speaker-test -Dplug:surround51 -c6 -l1 -twav
```

eveyting sounds fine but when I am using System Settings > Sound > Test Sound,  the results differ. I got poor performance on right channels(right channels pause about every 0,5 sec). While listening to music I get this poor performance from the second test and I do not get why.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, speaker-test calls on ALSA directly for the test whereas Ubuntu uses PulseAudio to interface with ALSA. That's why you're hearing a difference.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1794581

Comment: Can I force my ubuntu to always call on ALSA directly so that I always get better sound ?

Comment: Did you read through that forum post?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried to make my Rhythmbox work with alsa and I have followed this instruction: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/03/how-to-switch-to-alsa-or-oss-instead-of.html. Unfortunately the sound is still poor. I do not know what else should I do to receive pure sound from the 1st test while listening to music.